# How to JOIN a table to a ranked SELECT query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 different tables in my database by the name of: rank, settings.

Here is how each table looks like with a few records in them:

### Table #rank:

```
id  points userid
--  ----- ------
 1    500      1
 2    300      2    
 3    900      3
 4   1500      4
 5    100      5
 6    700      6
 7    230      7
 8    350      8
 9    850      9
10    150     10
```

### Table #settings:

```
userid    active 
------    ------
     1         0
     2         1
     3         1
     4         1
     5         1
     6         0
     7         1
     8         1
     9         0
    10         1
```

What I basically want to achieve is to select *everything* from #rank and rank the results by Descending order of points. 
For example:
The desired result would be the following:

```
rank points userid
---- ----- ------
   1   100      5   
   2   150     10   
   3   230      7
   4   300      2
   5   350      8
   6   500      1
   7   700      6
   8   850      9
   9   900      3
  10   1500     4
```

I have this query so far to rank the results, but I cannot join another table, because it gives me an error of not founding a column.

```
SELECT    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank, a.points, a.userid
FROM      rank p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  points DESC;
```

Any suggestion on how to achieve the desired result?

### EDIT:

You guys are totally right. I have actually forgotten to mention, that I only want to select users who's active number = 1. Apologies.

Comment: `from rank join other_table on ... cross join (select @currank ...) r`

Comment: Based on the desired results, why do you need to join the tables?

Comment: you can either have descending order or from lowest to highest, not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank, points, userid
FROM 
(SELECT rr.points, rr.userid 
FROM rank rr INNER JOIN settings sr ON sr.userid=rr.userid
AND sr.active=1
ORDER BY rr.points DESC) AS M, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r;
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/027efd/37)

Not sure this is what you wanted.

Comment: Wow, this is actually what I always wanted! Thank you very much man, you are a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

Your query works almost, there are only two minor problems.

MySQL cannot find the column, because you have `from rank p`, but select columns `a.points, a.userid`. Changing to `from rank a` fixes this one. The second problem is the sort order, change `desc` to `asc` and you get the desired order

```
SELECT    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank, a.points, a.userid
FROM      rank a, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  points asc
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f7bb/3)